# how to use select for multiple fields using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a character vector of field names that I want to select using dplyr.  I'm using the underscore version of select_().

```
select(mtcars, mpg)                   # works OK
select(mtcars, mpg, disp, am)         # works OK for multiple fields
```

now let's use the underscore version

```
fie <- c("mpg")             
select_(mtcars, fie)                  # works OK for one
fie <- c("mpg", "disp", "am")
select_(mtcars, fie)                  # problem:  only returns one column
select_(mtcars, ~fie)                 # problem:  doesn't work
```

I'm confused as to how to get this to work. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use select:

```
select(mtcars, one_of(fie))
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer works great. But what is this function "one_of()" ?  I couldn't find it in any help text: dplyr, R Help,

Comment: @hackR See the help page for `select` to see all of the special functions that work with it (including `one_of`).

Answer (score 6):

you should use the `.dots=` parameter of the standard evaluation version of the function.

```
select_(mtcars, .dots=fie)
```